# Why all religions worship Sun?

Tags: worship, other-religions, surya

I don't know that why every religions worship the Sun? Is there any big reason?

Comment: There was an awareness from the very beginning that the Sun with its light and heat made life possible. Thus the Sun is a very good symbol of the higher power that sustains life.

Comment: Visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_deity

Comment: Your question seems off-topic to me as you are talking about all religions and the answer could be too broad for this site. Please narrow it down. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to narrow your question down to why Hindus worship the Sun, that may be more acceptable.